# setting up a Java.time datePicker

Tags: java, android-studio, datepicker, java-time

I'm switching my app over to Java.time from using the built in Gregorian calendar as I've been told its a better way to go. Is there a way to do a date picker like I've done in the code below with java.time? If not, is there something similar?

```
 private void buildDatePicker(){
        final String myFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"; //sets format in which to show date
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());

        Date c = calendar.getTime(); //gets the current date
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c); //runs date through formatter
        etDate.setText(formattedDate); // sets the etDate edittext to the current date


        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
              
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);



                etDate.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }

        };

        etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), datePicker, calendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is neither complete nor consistent. And I do not do Android, so I am not familiar with the specific framework classes. So I cannot provide a complete example.

But I can show some rough code translated to use *java.time*.

```
private void buildDatePicker ( )
{

    // Automatically localize the format of the date string.
    // Perhaps not make `formatter` object `final` as the user's locale might change during runtime.
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.getDefault() );
    etDate.setText( myLocalDate.format( formatter ) ); // sets the etDate edittext to the current date

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
        {
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth );  // Uses sane numbering for year and month, unlike the `Calendar`/`Date`.
            etDate.setText( myLocalDate.format( formatter ) );
        }
    };

    etDate.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog( getContext() , datePicker , myLocalDate.getYear() , myLocalDate.getMonthValue() , myLocalDate.getDayOfMonth() )
                    .show();
        }
    } );
}
```

Much simpler with *java.time* than with the terrible legacy classes `Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.